# How to return multiple object type for ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have upgraded my project to use ASP.NET MVC4 from MVC3. Now my controller is using ApiController instead of Controllers. Previously I was using a function as:

```
 public JsonResult GetPermissions(string portfolioId)
 {
     //DO THE DATA FETCH
     return Json(new { PermissionValues = permissionValues,       UserPermissions = userPermissions, OwnerValues = ownerList },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

I would like to do similar operation using ApiControllers. I do not want to create a separate object where the the object will have 3 properties [since I am returning 3 lists]. I was trying to use `HttpResponseMessage<Object>` as return type of the function but doesn't seem to work though.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage<Object> GetPermissions(string portfolioId)
    {
      //DO THE DATA FETCH
      HttpResponseMessage<Object> response = new HttpResponseMessage<Object>(new { Users = listedUsers, PermissionValues = permissionValues });
      return response;
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue that you have is that the default serializer for json responses in the Beta bits cannot serialize anonymous types.  You need to use a formatter that can, such as one based on Json.NET (which will be built-in in the next drop).  To make this work with the Beta, your code would change to something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var content = new { Users = new List<string> { "John", "Mary" }, Permissions = new List<string> { "User", "Admin" } };
    return new HttpResponseMessage<object>(content, new[] { new JsonNetFormatter() });
}
```

Which would yield a response like this:

```
{"Users":["John","Mary"],"Permissions":["User","Admin"]}
```

Once the RC is available, your existing code should work fine.

Update:

In order for this code to compile, you need an implementation for JsonNetFormatter.  You can find an implementation provided by Henrik (MSFT) at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-JSONNET-with-ASPNET-b2423706#content or from the WebApiContrib project at https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Formatting.JsonNet/JsonNetFormatter.cs.

Note, they both suffer from the same bug in the OnWriteToStreamAsync method.  Those implementations close the underlying stream.  You need to change the using statements to look like this:

```
using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding)) { CloseOutput = false })
```

Henrik noted this in his blog but neither his sample nor the contrib one have been updated and I just haven't had the time to commit the fix to the contrib project.  ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a question on this - I added Newtonsoft.Json reference but when I trying to build, it is throwing the exception "The type or namespace name 'JsonNetFormatter' could not be found".

Comment: It's such a bad idea to stick a formatter inside the `HttpResponseMessage`. Conneg won't work with this implementation. If the OP doesn't need Conneg, why bother using Web API? just return it with MVC `JsonResult`. On the other hand, this code will break for the next with of the product which doesn't contain generic response and request messages.

Comment: @tugberk I agree with you that, generally speaking, it is preferable to take advantage of content negotiation.  However, the OP clearly intended to return a json response explicitly.

Comment: @DPeden then, nothing wrong with `JsonResult` as the OP is using MVC. that example is totally against the main principle of ASP.NET Web API. If the intention is only return Json response for every request, then I suggest to remove all other formatters except for `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`.